# how to optimize windows phone nested list box?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

here is my data source type

```
public class Part
{
    public int PartNumber { get; set; }
    public string ar_PartNumber { get; set; }
    public List<PartSuras> PartSuras { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public string ar_PageNumber { get; set; }

}

public class PartSuras
{
    public int SuraID { get; set; }
    public string ar_SuraID { get; set; }

    public string SuraTitle { get; set; }
    public string SuraTitleEn { get; set; }
    public int StartVerseID { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public string ar_PageNumber { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the nested listboxs

```
 <ListBox  Loaded="list_Index_Loaded" Name="list_Index" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-12,-40,-12,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="480" BorderBrush="#FFCADBBD" Margin="0,-12" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" Background="#FFD2BC70" Foreground="Black" Name="bt_part" Tag="{Binding PageNumber}" Tap="bt_part_Tap" >
                                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Center">
                                    <Run Text="الجزء "></Run>
                                    <Run Text="{Binding ar_PartNumber}"></Run>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </Button>
                                <ListBox Name="list_sura" ItemsSource="{Binding PartSuras}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Button  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="480" Margin="0,-12"  BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" Background="#FFE5DCAA" Foreground="Black" Name="bt_part" Tag="{Binding PageNumber}" Tap="bt_part_Tap" >
                                                <Grid Width="430" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Left">
                                                     <Run Text="{Binding ar_SuraID}"></Run>
                                                     <Run Text="-"></Run>
                                                     <Run Text="{Binding SuraTitle}"></Run>
                                                    </TextBlock>
                                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding ar_PageNumber}"></TextBlock>
                                                </Grid>

                                            </Button>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListBox>
```

this is kind of slow it takes almost 3 secs to only build the listboxes -i meseured the time of build the data source and it's okay- in Lumia 920 (1 GB ram) device, how can i optimize that?

would the performance be better if i removed the listboxes and created the controls in code behind?

Comment: How much is you data(number of records)?

Comment: Try replacing StackPanel inside the first ListBox DataTemplage to Grid. and also try setting height/width of the first Listbox

Comment: the items count is  30 main items and 114 childs

Comment: Did you tried my above comment?

Comment: yup, it seems lighter but not very noticeable i still get 2 seconds time to load bind the data

Comment: Does your First ListBox container is scrolviewer?

Comment: yes, the first ListBox container is scrolviewer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55647/discussion-between-muhammad-saifullah-and-hager-aly).

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need scrolling (you have `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"`), try using `ItemsControl` instead, it should perform better.

Comment: thanks, that reduced  the time by one second, it was 3 secs before

Answer (score 0):

Use LongListSelector for your outer Listbox and ItemsControl for your inner Listbox. Because LongListSelector is more optimized than ListBox, where as you cannot use a nested longlistselector which leads to scrolling and virtualization problem